# Document.onload not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I write `document.onload` code inside my head tag.. but it doesn't seems to work.
here is my code..

```
<head>
<script>
    document.onload = function () {
        alert("Window Loaded...!!");
    }
</script>
</head>
```

But if i replace  with `window.onload` it perfectly works!!
What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong ??

Comment: What browser (and version of browser) do you use? I think that some do not support the `document.onload` function. Check these answers for a bit more information about the diff between `document.onload` and `window.onload`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/1980359 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371558/1980359

Comment: I use Chrome, Version 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: I have never heard about `document.onload`. I guess the problem is that `document.onload` is not a valid property of Document elements (it just doesn't exist).

Comment: Chrome does not support `document.onload`.

Comment: It supports.. See this link.. http://goo.gl/G1Yasu I have shared my bowser console screenshot

Comment: Every resource i can find on the net says that chrome (or most of the major browsers) does not support it, or don't mention the event at all, except your screenshot. Your code does not  work, which also indicates that **it is not supported**. If you are 100% certain that it still is supported, keep using the code you provided, cause if it is, it should work.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I'm aware, the closest you can come to your method is:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   /* your logic here */
});
```

The problem you have is `document` may not have a method of `onload` for a particular browser. Luckily! The `window` does in most cases. :) Give that a try for your JavaScript invocation.

Comment: No I dont agree.. each and every element in the DOM will have all the events. I am using Visual studio.. and it shows me onload for document also.

Comment: Good idea... It worked!! but tell me why it doesn't work when i directly add document.onload??

Comment: Are you sure?  I've tried something like "document.body.getElementById()" and it hasn't worked; yet "document.getElementById" has.

Comment: @Uthaiah the answer below gave a great example. Pretty much said everything I might have :-)

Comment: document.body has only three DOM access functions document.body.getElementsByClassName(),getElementsByTagName() and getElementsByTagNameNS()

Comment: also note that `window.onload` is triggered only after all external resources including images and scripts are loaded.